# Mysql2 Gem Install Make Error. (Windows 7)

Tags: rubygems, installation, mysql2

I am struggling to install mysql2 gem 0.2.7, this is the output I get:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=X: --with-mysql-lib=X:\lib 

--no-rdoc --no-ri
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H -IX:/include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall -funroll-loops  -o client.o -c client.c
client.c: In function 'rb_mysql_client_query':
client.c:361:11: warning: unused variable 'r'
gcc -I. -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H -IX:/include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall -funroll-loops  -o mysql2_ext.o -c mysql2_ext.c
gcc -I. -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H -IX:/include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall -funroll-loops  -o result.o -c result.c
result.c: In function 'rb_mysql_result_fetch_fields':
result.c:318:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
gcc -shared -s -o mysql2.so client.o mysql2_ext.o result.o -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby192/lib -LX:\lib -LX:/lib -L.  -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import mysql2-i386-mingw32.def  -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -llibmysql  -lshell32 -lws2_32  
client.o: In function `nogvl_connect':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:111: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'
client.o: In function `nogvl_init':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:102: undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
client.o: In function `set_ssl_options':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:612: undefined reference to `mysql_ssl_set@24'
client.o: In function `set_charset_name':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:600: undefined reference to `mysql_options@12'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:602: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
client.o: In function `set_connect_timeout':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:571: undefined reference to `mysql_options@12'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:573: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
client.o: In function `set_reconnect':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:554: undefined reference to `mysql_options@12'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:556: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
client.o: In function `nogvl_ping':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:530: undefined reference to `mysql_ping@4'
client.o: In function `rb_mysql_client_thread_id':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:522: undefined reference to `mysql_thread_id@4'
client.o: In function `rb_mysql_client_last_id':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:502: undefined reference to `mysql_insert_id@4'
client.o: In function `nogvl_store_result':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:242: undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4'
client.o: In function `nogvl_read_query_result':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:234: undefined reference to `mysql_read_query_result@4'
client.o: In function `rb_mysql_client_server_info':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:481: undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_version@4'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:482: undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_info@4'
client.o: In function `rb_mysql_client_info':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:454: undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version@0'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:455: undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info@0'
client.o: In function `rb_mysql_client_escape':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:422: undefined reference to `mysql_real_escape_string@16'
client.o: In function `nogvl_send_query':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:222: undefined reference to `mysql_send_query@12'
client.o: In function `nogvl_close':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:148: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
client.o: In function `rb_raise_mysql2_error':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:77: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:78: undefined reference to `mysql_sqlstate@4'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:92: undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4'
client.o: In function `rb_mysql_client_affected_rows':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:510: undefined reference to `mysql_affected_rows@4'
client.o: In function `rb_mysql_client_async_result':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:266: undefined reference to `mysql_field_count@4'
client.o: In function `nogvl_close':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:148: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
client.o: In function `init_mysql2_client':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/client.c:640: undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info@0'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_fetch_field':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:82: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field_direct@8'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:70: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_fetch_fields':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:314: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4'
result.o: In function `nogvl_fetch_row':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:61: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_free_result':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:40: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_fetch_row':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:133: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_fields@4'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:134: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_lengths@4'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_free_result':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:40: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_fetch_row':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:136: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_each':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:381: undefined reference to `mysql_num_rows@4'
result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_free_result':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.7\ext\mysql2/result.c:40: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing mysql2 gem with rails 3 on Windows, you can refer to the detailed steps of installation on -

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I found this guide shortly after posting and that is what got it to the point of making but it continues to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building as a straight ruby extension:

```
subst X: "C:\Data\MySQL"
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- -with-mysql-dir=X: --with-mysql-lib=X:\lib --with-mysql-include=X:\include
```

I needed the separate include directive, as I'm using MySQL 5.5 (and looks like the directory layout has changed post 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

The procedure detailed in the rorguide didn't work for me either.
I've solved copying the libmysql.lib file from the mysql community server zip file (win x86) directly into the ext\mysql2 directory of the gem. This seem to make it correctly find the lib.
Version 0.3.2 of the mysql2 gem seems to hang upon query tough, but the master branch from github (https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) has it fixed.